# If condition not working for ChartJS

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, chart.js

I am trying to chartjs dashboard page.I am got some issues in bottom label color problem.I get the solution but if condtion not working to me.Please any one help me.

My Code.....

```
generateLabels: function(chart) {
   var get_label = _.pluck(chart.data.datasets, 'label');
   var join_label = _.flatten(get_label);
   var get_color = _.pluck(chart.data.datasets, 'backgroundColor');
   var join_color = _.flatten(get_color);
   var get_data = {
        label: join_label,
        backgroundColor: join_color
  }
  for (k = 0; k < get_data.label.length; k++) {
     return get_data.label.map(function(label, i) {
        if(label != 'undefined'){
           return {
               text: label,
               fillStyle: get_data.backgroundColor[i]
           };
        }
      });
   }
```

}

if(label != 'undefined') this condition not working...

Comment: `label != 'undefined'` is testing if label is string with value 'undefined'. Try `value === undefined` or `!value`.

Comment: Also the `for` loop doesn't make sense. The loop variable `k` isn't used and the first statement of the loop body is a `return`. That's a quite convoluted and misleading way to express a simple `if (get_data.label.length > 0)`.  Additionally I would explicitly return `undefined` or even better `null` in the cases where the function(s) don't run into a `return` if there is at least one code path ending at a `return` in a function. Otherwise it's not clear to the reader if this is on purpose or actually an error/oversight.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `if(label != 'undefined')` for `if(label)`. It should works

Comment: if(label) condition is working but no any return value.I got one issues in chartjs bundle js file.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined
   at Chart.bundle.min.js:14
    at Object.r.each (Chart.bundle.min.js:13)
    at n.fit (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at n.update (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)
    at a (Chart.bundle.min.js:14)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that undefined is a keyword so you don't have to put it between quotes.
Try with if (label != null && label != undefined) { ... }