# ChartJS: Adjust Tooltip with sums in body

Tags: javascript, chart.js, nested-loops, react-chartjs

I have the following output at the moment:

[image]

However, I would like to have the following table:

- Minimum: 90
- 25th: 95
- 25th to Median: 100
- (the blue one I dont want to show)
- 75th: 105
- Max: 110

I have the following code, I hope this will be enough:

```
const data = {
  labels: [
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[0].short,
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[1].short,
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[2].short,
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[3].short,
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[4].short,
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[5].short,
    REMockProducts[0].valuations[6].short,
  ],
  datasets: [
    {
      label: "Minimum",
      data: [
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[0].min,
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[1].min,
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[2].min,
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[3].min,
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[4].min,
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[5].min,
        REMockProducts[0].valuations[6].min,
      ],
      toCheck: 0,
    },
    {
      label: "25th",
      data: [
        lwpercDistance(0, 0)[0],
        lwpercDistance(0, 1)[0],
        lwpercDistance(0, 2)[0],
        lwpercDistance(0, 3)[0],
        lwpercDistance(0, 4)[0],
        lwpercDistance(0, 5)[0],
        lwpercDistance(0, 6)[0],
      ],
      toCheck: 1,
    },
    {
      label: "25th to Median",
      data: [
        medianDistance(0, 0)[0],
        medianDistance(0, 1)[0],
        medianDistance(0, 2)[0],
        medianDistance(0, 3)[0],
        medianDistance(0, 4)[0],
        medianDistance(0, 5)[0],
        medianDistance(0, 6)[0],
      ],
      toCheck: 2,
    },
    {
      label: false,
      data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
      toCheck: 3,
    },
    {
      label: "75th",
      data: [
        hipercDistance(0, 0)[0],
        hipercDistance(0, 1)[0],
        hipercDistance(0, 2)[0],
        hipercDistance(0, 3)[0],
        hipercDistance(0, 4)[0],
        hipercDistance(0, 5)[0],
        hipercDistance(0, 6)[0],
      ],
      toCheck: 4,
    },
    {
      label: "Max",
      data: [
        maxDistance(0, 0)[0],
        maxDistance(0, 1)[0],
        maxDistance(0, 2)[0],
        maxDistance(0, 3)[0],
        maxDistance(0, 4)[0],
        maxDistance(0, 5)[0],
        maxDistance(0, 6)[0],
      ],
      toCheck: 5
    },
  ],
};

[...] <Bar
        data={data}
        options={{
          plugins: {
            legend: {
              position: "top",
            },
            tooltips: {
              callbacks: {
                label : function(data, tooltip) {
                  let k = 0;
                  let j = 0;
                  for (k; k < 5; k++) {
                    for (j; j < 7; j++) {
                      if (k > 0) {
                        let tooltip =
                          data.datasets[0].data[j] + data.datasets[k].data[j];
                      } else {
                        let tooltip = data.datasets[0].data[j];
                      }
                    }
                    return { text: tooltip };
                  }
                },
              },
            },
          },
          indexAxis: "y",
          scales: {
            x: {
              stacked: true,
              ticks: {
                autoSkip: false,
              },
            },
            y: {
              stacked: true,
              ticks: {
                autoSkip: false,
              },
            },
          },
        }}
      />
```

It is probably pretty clear that I am inexperiences with nested loops in JS.
The basic idea was to run through each dataset and either take the face value of the "Minimum" data or add them up.
Hovering over my `tooltip` variable actually shows the following:
[image]

I clearly must make an obvious mistake I can't figure out.

Links that helped me so far:

- [ChartJs different data for Tooltips](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65981839/chartjs-different-data-for-tooltips)
- [If condition not working for ChartJS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48514213/if-condition-not-working-for-chartjs)

[Edit] I actually just realized that I did the sum incorrectly. Doesn't change much though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically your question is two parts.

1. Filter the 0 values
2. Add accumulative sum to each datapoint in tooltip

I simplified your code as you had a for loop which was not needed as it could be done all in Chart JS tooltip.

I created a video with the entire breakdown and explanation. You can watch here for more understanding: [ChartJS: Adjust Tooltip with sums in body](https://youtu.be/FOZooZYK4v0)

See code below:

```
<script>
  // setup 
  const data = {
    labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    },{
      label: '# of Cost',
      data: [11, 4, 0, 7, 10, 13],
      backgroundColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    },{
      label: '# of Sales',
      data: [10, 0, 10, 0, 10, 22],
      backgroundColor: 
        'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
      borderColor: 'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  };

  // tooltip block
  const tooltip = {
    yAlign: 'bottom',
    filter: function filterZeroData(datapoint) {
      return datapoint.raw > 0;
    },
    callbacks: {
      label: function(context) {
        const stackedBarArray = [];
        for (i = 0; i <= context.datasetIndex; i++){
          stackedBarArray.push(context.parsed._stacks.y[i]);
        };
        console.log(stackedBarArray);

        // reduce array
        const reducer = (accumulator, currentValue) => accumulator + currentValue;

        // return value in tooltip
        console.log(context.dataset.label)
        const labelName = context.dataset.label;
        const labelValue = stackedBarArray.reduce(reducer);
        return `${labelName} ${labelValue}`;
      }
    }
  };

  // config 
  const config = {
    type: 'bar',
    data,
    options: {
      plugins: {
        tooltip,
      },
      scales: {
        x: {
          stacked: true
        },
        y: {
          stacked: true,
          beginAtZero: true
        }
      }
    }
  };

  // render init block
  const myChart = new Chart(
    document.getElementById('myChart'),
    config
  );
</script>
```

Comment: Implemented it, everything went perfectly, thank you.
Now I can finally go to my next steps - maybe I can find some solutions at your channel :)